# Video is darker after I render animation

Tags: cycles-render-engine, export, lighting

I am currently rendering an animation. When I render the frames as PNGs the color is fine. However when I export as animation from the video editor all the foreground in my animation is dark. Does anyone know why this may be? I am using PSA addon for my lighting.

Comment: How do you export? Which color management was useg in your PNGs and did you set it correctly in the Video Sequence Editor? Does it look as it should in the Video Sequence Editor?